# how to change UI elements after running code

Tags: user-interface, customtkinter

im trying to make a tab like system for my program, and im using the side bar code from the [complex example](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/examples/complex_example.py) and i want to be able to change the entire UI by pressing any of the buttons, is that possible? like the small tabs system, but i want the whole thing to change not just some small part of it.

i tried making the tab system the library for the whole thing but i cant really do much with it, i cant change the elements around

to simplify: i read the docs and found nothing